# Email verification before user creation

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

According to the [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims), it is possible to have email verified when user().onCreate is triggered. From my understanding, you can send email verification link only after creating an account. How it is possible?

```js
// On sign up.
exports.processSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  // Check if user meets role criteria.
  if (
    user.email &&
    user.email.endsWith('@admin.example.com') &&
    user.emailVerified  // Is this can be true at this moment!?
  ) {
      // Grant access
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial claims for a user profile are determined by the provider that creates the initial ID token for that user. So any provider can set the `emailVerified` claim if they want.

Example of built-in providers that do that:

- When you [sign the user in through an email link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) it implicitly already verified that they have access to the email address, so `emailVerified` is set to `true`.
- Certain providers already know that the user owns a certain email address, such as Google for `@gmail.com` and Facebook for `@facebook.com` addresses, and may set `emailVerified` to `true` for such addresses automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Then I won't check an email verification in this trigger functions as long as only an email and password signup is supported.